# Describing ENI error when executing DataSync task in Fargate/Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-datasync

I am experiencing the error "InvalidRequestException: Invalid request made for describing ENI" when executing AWS DataSync task from Fargate/Lambda. What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the cause of this. The issue is because I am using a VPC with the transfer. To fix this, the Fargate/Lambda role should allow the following:

```
- Effect: 'Allow'
  Action:
    - 'ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces'
  Resource: '*'
```